# Why AllGather() fails in for loops with different iteration values?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I've coded following code to experiment with AllGather():

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

a = None
if rank == 0:
    a = 2
if rank == 1:
    a = 3
z = 2
for i in range(0, a):
    z = comm.allgather(z)

print(z, rank)
comm.barrier()
```

I run it as follows:

> mpiexec  -n 2 python3  allgather.py

I get the following output:

> [[2, 2], [2, 2]] 0

The 2nd processor is stuck and program doesn't terminate.

The output should be:

> [[2, 2], [2, 2]] 0
>
> [[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]] 1

I fail to see why 2nd processor gets stuck. It runs correctly if I set  a = 2 
in both processors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second process gets stuck because it is trying to gather from all processes, the second process is waiting for the first to join it in the `allgather()` operation and will wait indefinitely for this to happen.

It's kind of hard to tell you a good way to fix this without knowing a practical application.
But generally all processes will have to partake in a gather operation, the simple fix is to just let process 0 partake without using the result:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

a = None
if rank == 0:
    a = 2
if rank == 1:
    a = 3
z = 2
old_z = None
for i in range(0, a):
    if i == a-1:
        old_z = z 
    z = comm.allgather(z)

if rank == 0:
    comm.allgather(old_z)

print(z, rank)
comm.barrier()
```

This is not a very elegant solution but it does provide your desired output. Note how I had to store the value of z from the processes previous iteration to get anything close to your desired behavior.

If we don't store the previous value of z we get the following result:

> [[2, 2], [2, 2]] 0
>
> [[[2, 2], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [2, 2]]] 1

Comment: Ah, I see it now! I also tried z = comm.gather(z, root=rank) but it fails also. Any ideas on that?

Comment: What ``gather`` does is just collect data from all processes in one, meaning you still have to send in each one, but there is just one recipient. I know, the naming is a little confusing. Sadly mpi4py doesn't exactly have good documentation, take a look at: http://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html
If it whatever you are looking for is not documented there, take a look at the C-API for MPI.

Comment: @H2O can you suggest what is going wrong in the script posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72522846/problems-with-mpi-comm-world-gather-for-a-list-in-python/72538180#72538180. Thanks